# How does manipulation of a char array cause a stack overflow?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

If there is a blatantly obvious flaw, I'm sorry. I'm fairly new to memory, so I have some understanding on how stack overflows work and as far as I know, nothing I'm doing should cause a stack overflow. All I'm doing is changing the character in a string.

I know arrays are pointers, but would changing the value cause a stack overflow?

Here is the concerning function:

```
char base[] = "aaaaa";
void changeLetters(int position) { // Stack overflow happens around here
    if (base[position] != 'z') {
        base[position]++;
    }

    // When I include a cout here, I also get a stack overflow

    if (position == 4 && base[position] != 'z') {
        changeLetters(position);
    }
    else if (base[position] == 'z' && position != 0) {
        base[position] = 'a';
        changeLetters(position - 1);
    }
    else if (position < 4) {
        changeLetters(position + 1);
    }
}
```

When not having `std::cout`, I get the

> Unhandled exception at 0x767C3210 (KernelBase.dll) in passwordCracker.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x01002FFC).

Otherwise

> Unhandled exception at 0x009C38B9 in passwordCracker.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x006D2F8C).

Edit:
The function is called in the main loop. The value passed is the length of the string (4), and it works its way through. One odd thing I didn't mention is that it works perfectly if I cycle through a smaller amount of letters (a, b, c, d) but I only recieve a stack overflow if I have it cycle through the alphabet.

Comment: How is `base` declared/defined? ([mcve] please)

Comment: How is this function called?  What value is being passed for `position`?

Comment: @NathanOliver it is a character array! Sorry, I forgot to mention when first writing the question.

Comment: I am almost sure you have an infinite recursion, I just cant wrap my head around what the methods is doing...

Comment: btw "I know arrays are pointers," no, they are not.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! I'm attempting to fix that. Could one of you offer an explanation on why this causes a stack overflow?

Comment: the function is void so no return...also the variables are not static so are lost every time the process leaves the function...also try using an initialization list first and get it working.  also loop inside of the function and output from there...also dynamically create the array inside of the function and loop inside of the function to get rid of a lot of issues...

Comment: @user463035818 haha, this is my first time using a recursive functioning, so it was my challenge to make a bruteforce program. And regarding the pointer thing, upon further googling, my misconception was that a variable to an array acts as a pointer to that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is iterating over all strings of length `5` made up of the alphabet `a-z`. This is not a problem by itself, however you have to make sure that the maximal call depth is not too large.

In each iteration of `changeLetters` you are increasing at most one letter once and then call again to `changeLetters` and you make at most one such call.

Therefore your call graph is completely linear, for each of the `26^5` strings you are making another recursive call in depth and so the call stack at the end will be about that large. The problem is, that this is a very large number `26^5 = 11881376` and may easily be larger than the stack space you may use.

You need to make the linear call graph into one with branches, by e.g. using a loop over the current character's position instead of calling `changeLetters` each time.

Answer (score 1):

The recursion isn't infinite, but it's deep.  Deep enough to blow up the stack.

The function uses recursion each time it increments a letter.  And because there are 5 characters holding 26 possible values each, the recursion is 26<sup>5</sup> = 11881376 levels deep.  I'm not sure how big your stack is, but it's not big enough to handle that many levels.  So  you get a stack overflow.

Switch to an iterative solution using nested loops.